# Correct way to introduce acronyms

Tags: acronyms

What is the correct method of introducing the expanded form for Acronym in the bracket? is it expanded form first and then the acronym in bracket or Vica-Versa. 
Also, what is the difference in introducing the acronyms to the American audience or to the British audience?

Comment: Acronyms are encouraged only to the audience that understands them.  Else the expanded forms are advised.  To help those who might need help, the expanded forms are given in brackets, but people use the other way round too. Expansion at the first time use is done such that in the succeeding part, the acronym could be used without expansion.

Comment: what about the audience?

Comment: You may refer to the different types of audience. Tech writing says, audience can be high-tech, low-tech or lay.  For the high-tech, acronyms need no expansion. Example, a coder can easily understand what is html.

Comment: I mean the British and American Audience.

Comment: I am not sure whether what I said will be different for the American or British audience. Possibly someone else could help you.

Comment: Purely a matter of style.

Comment: Yes, thanks to everyone for the responses :-)

Answer (score 1):

There's no one correct way to introduce abbreviations. The U.S. Government Publishing Office Style Manual says (p. 221),

> Abbreviations not generally known should be followed in the text by
>   the spelled-out forms in parentheses the first time they occur.

However, it also gives examples (p. 196) of putting the abbreviations in parentheses. For acronyms that are well known, the *Associated Press Style Book and Libel Manual*, Sixth Trade Edition (Reading, Mass.: Addison-Wesley Publishing, 1996), gave the example of NASA, the National Aeronautics and Space Administration (p. 136): “*NASA* is acceptable on first reference [that is, without explanation].… mention the full name later.” But as the comments point out, make sure that using the abbreviation actually helps communication.

Comment: Please give attributed links to quotes, and quotes rather than paraphrases.

Comment: I'll have to look up the page in my AP manual. I don’t have it with me, and I’m not sure the AP manual is online; I think you have to buy it (I bought my paper copy). I wasn't looking at GPO online. Those are the page numbers in my copy of the manual.

Comment: Agreement. There is some degree of variation in style, and often an office or university department or newspaper editorial office, etc, will have a style guide indicating the local preferred use. Probably as long as you have a particular basically sensible style, and use it consistently, it will be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question of style, rather than a grammatical rule.  Either of the following are valid usage.

1. Many manufacturers now use Solid-state Disk (SSD) storage.
2. Many manufacturers now use SSD (Solid-state Disk) storage.

I prefer 1. but I'd have no problem to 2.  I wouldn't even object to text that mixed 1. and 2., but I would prefer a writer who was consistent.

The more important thing is that your first use of the abbreviation has the expanded form beside it.